# Chemical Equillibria Comparisons

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

In which of the following reactions is the equilibrium farthest to the left?

a) $\ce{P4O10 + $x$ H2O <=> 4 H3PO4(aq)}$

b) $\ce{AlCl3 + $x$ H2O <=> [Al(H2O)6]^3+ + 3 Cl- (aq)}$

c) $\ce{Li2O + $x$ H2O <=> 2 Li+(aq) + 2 OH- (aq)}$

d) $\ce{H2S + H2O <=> H3O+ + HS- (aq)}$

e) $\ce{CaC2 + $x$ H2O <=> Ca^2+(aq) + 2 OH- (aq) + C2H2(g)}$

The correct answer is d, but I'm not sure how to compare these equilibria.  I know that the answer can't be e, since the evolution and purging of gas will drive the equilibrium forward.  Also, the dissociation of ions in water is favorable due to solvation, so that rules out c and b.

But I'm not sure how to compare the remaining two reactions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By farthest to the left, do you mean which one will have the smallest equilibrium constant?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is how the question is to be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

You have already ruled out the equations **b**, **c**, and **e**.

> But I'm not sure how to compare the remaining two reactions.

Have a look at equation **a** again.

The reaction of $\ce{P4O10}$ with water generates phosphoric acid ($\ce{H3PO4}$), which is a fairly strong three-protonic acid ($\mathrm{pK_{a1} = 2.16; pK_{a2} = 7.21}$).

As a result, subsequent deprotonation of phosphoric acid
$$\ce{H3PO4 + H2O <=> H3O+ + H2PO4-}$$

will pull the equilibrium in equation **a** to the right.

Hydrogen sulfide ($\ce{H2S}$), on the other hand, is a rather weak acid with $\mathrm{pK_{a} = 7.0}$. Consequently, you will find a significant amount of undissociated hydrogen sulfide in aqueous solution. Therefore, the correct answer in the comparison is indeed **d**.

Comment: Isn't the hydrolysis of phosphorpentoxid irreversible just because of the thermodynamics? I doubt this has anything to do with the phosphoric acid getting deprotonated. Stated otherwise: I highly doubt that I would be able to generate phosphorpentoxid from phosphoric acid just by removing the water from it - Phosphorpentoxid is just energetically unfavored thus driving "equilibrium" to the product side in a quasi irreversible fashion. Besides, this argument ignores intermediate formation of meta and ortho phosphoric acid that is already irreversible.